# Javascript: Change the solution to O(n log n)

Tags: javascript

Below is the solution to a question I came across while learning Javascript:-
Question:- Find the highest average runs scored against a team by a batsmen  he has played in the tournament.
Below are the runs scored against the teams he has scored in the tournament:-

```
[    
    ["Srilanka", 23], 
    ["Srilanka", 230],
    ["Pakistan", 127],
    ["India", 3],
    ["India", 71],
    ["Australia", 310],
    ["India", 22],
    ["Pakistan", 1]
]
```

The solution code I had written with was :-

```
function getHighscoreAaverage (input) {
try {
    var matches = JSON.parse(input);
} catch(e) {
    console.error('Error parsing input string...');
    return '';
}

var average_runs = [];
var high_average = 0;
var high_average_country = '';

for ( var i = 0; i< matches.length; i++) {

    if(typeof average_runs[matches[i][0]] === "undefined") {
        average_runs[matches[i][0]] = {
            "total": 0,
            "count": 0,
            "average": 0
        }
    }

    average_runs[ matches[i][0] ]["total"] += matches[i][1];
    average_runs[ matches[i][0] ]["count"] += 1;
    average_runs[ matches[i][0] ]["average"] = average_runs[matches[i][0]]["total"] / average_runs[matches[i][0]]["count"];

}

for (country in average_runs) {
    if(average_runs[country]["average"] > high_average){
        high_average = average_runs[country]["average"];
        high_average_country = country;
    }
}


return high_average_country;
}
getHighscoreAaverage ('[    ["Srilanka", 23], ["Srilanka", 230],    ["Pakistan", 127],    ["India", 3],    ["India", 71],    ["Australia", 310],    ["India", 22],    ["Pakistan", 1]]');
```

I wanted to check with fellow programmers whether this code can be optimized further. I wanted to improve my coding level and any help on this will be deeply appreciated.

Suggested code:-
Note: below code doesnt give correct answer.

```
function getHighscoreAaverage (input) {
    try {
        var matches = JSON.parse(input);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error('Error parsing input string...');
        return '';
    }

    var average_runs = [];
    var high_average = 0;
    var high_average_country = '';

    for ( var i = 0; i< matches.length; i++) {

        if(typeof average_runs[matches[i][0]] === "undefined") {
            average_runs[matches[i][0]] = {
                "total": 0,
                "count": 0,
                "average": 0
            }
        }

        average_runs[ matches[i][0] ]["total"] += matches[i][1];
        average_runs[ matches[i][0] ]["count"] += 1;
        average_runs[ matches[i][0] ]["average"] = average_runs[matches[i][0]]["total"] / average_runs[matches[i][0]]["count"];

        if(average_runs[matches[i][0]]["average"] > high_average){
            high_average = average_runs[matches[i][0]]["average"];
            high_average_country = matches[i][0];
        }
    }

    return high_average_country;
}
```

Comment: For `O(n log n)` you need to prep the data first - like keep it in sorted manner (sorted by runs descending). You can simply avoid the second `for-loop` by keeping track of the *current highest average* and its *country* in the first `for-loop` itself.

Comment: wouldnt there be an additional loop iteration If i were to track current highest average and its country in the first for loop. I mean we will have to loop through average_runs to check highest average in each first for loop iteration.

Comment: No, just two variables `highestAverage` and `country` and an extra condition check to verify if the `average_runs[ matches[i][0] ]["average"]` is greater than `highestAverage`

Comment: You mean updated code:-

Comment: didn't understand *You mean updated code*

Comment: Not able to give the code as per your changes, so I have updated the question. Are you referring to above solution? If yes then the above solution doesnt give correct answer.

Comment: Why is that a wrong answer? It gives "Australia" as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firtsly, note that your original solution is O(n) ( assuming the implementation is smart enough ) so why do you want a O(nlogn) solution ?

anyway, in order to compare the highest avarage in place, we must first sort by item value to make running avarages monotonic ...

```js
var input = [    
    ["Srilanka", 23], 
    ["Srilanka", 230],
    ["Pakistan", 127],
    ["India", 3],
    ["India", 71],
    ["Australia", 310],
    ["India", 22],
    ["Pakistan", 1]
];

var result;

input
  .sort(function(a,b) { return a[1] - b[1]; })
  .reduce(function(a,n){
    if(!a[n[0]]) a[n[0]] = { count: 0, total: 0 };
    
    var entry = a[n[0]];
    
    entry.count ++;
    entry.total += n[1];
    
    var avg = entry.total / entry.count;
    
    if( !result || result.avg < avg )
      result = { name: n[0], avg: avg };
    
    return a;
    },{});

console.log(result);
```

just for your info, here is how I'd implement it ( with the help of underscore ), something like:

```js
var input = [    
  ["Srilanka", 23], 
  ["Srilanka", 230],
  ["Pakistan", 127],
  ["India", 3],
  ["India", 71],
  ["Australia", 310],
  ["India", 22],
  ["Pakistan", 1]
];

var highest_avarage = _.chain(input)
  .groupBy( entry => entry[0] )
  .map( (totals,name) => ({ name: name, avg: totals.reduce( (a,b)=>(a+b[1]), 0 ) / totals.length }) )
  .max( entry => entry.avg );

console.log(highest_avarage);
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just wanted to check  whether it can be optimized further for my learning. I came accross `map`, `reduce`, `filter` and thought whether this can be applicable here. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Ville, ok, I edit the answer with a simpler ( and faster solution ) ...

Comment: Thanks, it helped!